# SVG and javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

How can I create two SVG circle using Javascript and drag and drop to the circle? Do all browsers support in SVG?

Comment: Why do you need SVG to do that? You can do it with straight CSS+JS e.g. http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ + http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: SVG is images are scalable and the image can be zoomed without degradation. That's only i want SVG. CSS tricks is very useful for me. Thanks timoxley.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use SVG with Javascript is by using a library like [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/).

To determine browser support, check out http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Hi Otto Allmendinger. I'm very sorry to say. These information not enough for me.

Comment: This information is exactly what you need to know, without handing it to you on a plate.